# Refer to same ArrayList from multiple objects

Tags: java

I am wondering how i could refer to the same ArrayList from multiple objects.
The following is not a real world example, it's only made up for explanation purposes.

If I have a `CarCatalog` class with an `ArrayList` field:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

If i then create an instance of `CarCreator` and `CarDeleter`, and pass the `cars` field with it

```
CarCreator creator = new CarCreator(this.cars);
```

And assigns the parameter to a field in the `CarCreator` object:

```
class CarCreator {
    ArrayList<Car> cars;

    public CarCreator(ArrayList cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
}
```

Now, if I add a `Car` object in `CarCreator` to

```
this.cars
```

Is it going to be in the `CarCatalogs` field, too?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Rhetorical question is rhetorical. You could *try it* and find out. That being said, you don't seem to understand how objects work in Java; you may want to go through the tutorials provided by Oracle or get a good Beginner's book on Java. Not understanding the fundamentals will make attempting to write code very, very difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is. When you write:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
```

cars is not an `ArrayList`. It's a *reference* to an `ArrayList`. That's crucial, because when you pass `cars` around, you're passing a reference to the original list. Hence modifying the list in one object will mean those changes are visible in the second object.

There's a strong argument here for *immutable* objects. That is, objects that can't be changed. Obviously that's not practical all the time, so you need to be clear as to who owns the list, who's allowed to change it, and passing copies or immutable versions around wherever possible. This is often referred to as *defensive programming*.